# How to loop and compare multiple data passed from a single view Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have this function in my GlobalController:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $isChanged = false;

    if (!$request) {
        $isChanged = true;
    }

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->birth_date = $request->birth_date;

    $user->updated_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user->save();

    if ($isChanged == true) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('updated', "Successfully updated $request->first_name");
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('alert', "No changes $request->first_name");
    }
}
```

and in my view that is in relation to this function, I have this:

```
<div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="{{ $user->first_name }}" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
          <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="{{ $user->last_name }}" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="email">E-mail</label>
          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="" value="{{ $user->email }}" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="birth_date">Birth Date</label>
          <input name="birth_date" type="date" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->birth_date }}"  required>
     </div>
</div>
```

basically, this modal shows the current details that are in the database ( `value="{{ $user->last_name }}"` )

What I wish to happen is that, when the user saves the edit with no changes, it will proceed to the second return in the function of my controller which is `return redirect()->back()->with('alert', "No changes $request->first_name");`

but whenever I try to save and do not apply any changes it always proceeds to first return which is `return redirect()->back()->with('updated', "Successfully updated $request->first_name");`

I suspect that it may be because of my predefined value in modal view stated above. Is there any workaround in this? I want to notify the user that if there are no changes made, it will proceed to the second return.

Let me know if any further details are needed to solve this issue.

**EDIT:**

With the help of @Mozammil and @Manzurul Hoque Rumi, I was able to fix my issue using this function:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->birth_date = $request->birth_date;
    $user->locale_id = $request->locale_id;

    $isUserModified = $user->isDirty();
    $user->updated_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user->save();

    return $isUserModified
        ? redirect()->back()->with('updated', "Successfully updated $request->first_name")
        : redirect()->back()->with('alert', "No changes applied for $request->first_name");
}
```

If anyone can share the PHP equivalent of `isDirty()` for old versions will be a great help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `isDirty()` before the `save()` action. For example:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->birth_date = $request->birth_date;
    $user->updated_at = now();

    $isChanged = $user->isDirty(); 

    $user->save();

    return $isChanged 
        ? back()->with('updated', "Successfully updated $request->first_name")
        : back()->with('alert', "No changes $request->first_name");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has a built in function to detect if data is changed to compare with previous data. When you want to know if the model has been edited since it was queried from the database, or isn't saved at all, then you use the `->isDirty()` function.

[Laravel Source API](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_isDirty)

Comment: Is this the right way to do it in my function's case? 
`if ($user->isDirty()) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('updated', "Successfully updated $request->first_name");
        }`

Comment: If model changes then it will return true and false otherwise. So yes, you can do like this.

Comment: `if ($user->isDirty()) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('updated', "Successfully updated $request->first_name");
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('alert', "No changes applied for $request->first_name");
}` it always proceeds to second return even if I tested it and have done some information changes. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: before this condition you should use `$user->save()`.